# Is your cousin's wife or husband also a first cousin?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I know that two people are first cousins if their parents are siblings, but what do you call your cousin's wife or husband, are they still your first cousin?

Comment: I think we have a canonical Q&A on this...

Comment: I don't think there's a particular word for it if that's what you are looking for. They are not your cousins as a sister-in-law is not a sister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that two people are first cousins if their parents are siblings, but what do you call your cousin's wife or husband, are they still your first cousin?

No, cousins are related by blood, not by marriage.

OED
1b. spec. **A child of the brother or sister of either of one's parents; a person with whom one has one or more (typically two) grandparents in common;**